# Python recursive function to search a binary tree

Tags: python, recursion, binary-tree

Very new at Python and I'm trying to understand recursion over a binary tree. I've implemented a very simple tree, which funnily enough maps English characters to binary (1's and 0's). I've only used a very simple structure because I am struggling to get my head round a more complex question that I've been set. I figure if I can get my head round my example then I should be able to go away and look at the question I've been set myself.

The following creates the class BinaryTree and an instance of this

```
class BinaryTree:
    """A rooted binary tree"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

def is_empty(testtree: BinaryTree) -> bool:
        """Return True if tree is empty."""
        return testtree.root == testtree.left == testtree.right == None

def join(item: object, left: BinaryTree, right: BinaryTree) -> BinaryTree:
    """Return a tree with the given root and subtrees."""
    testtree = BinaryTree()
    testtree.root = item
    testtree.left = left
    testtree.right = right
    return testtree

EMPTY = BinaryTree()
C = join('C',EMPTY,EMPTY)
D = join('D',EMPTY,EMPTY)
E = join('E',EMPTY,EMPTY)
F = join('F',EMPTY,EMPTY)
A = join('A',C,D)
B = join('B',E,F)
BINARY = join('START',B,A)
```

I visualise it as follows

[Visualisation of the Binary tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmrEq.jpg)

Now I'm trying to create a function that will take two inputs, a BinaryTree and a single character and the output will be the binary code for the corresponding letter (as an example, D = " 10 "). I'm outputting as a string rather than an integer. My function and test case as follows

```
# global variable
result = ''

#Convert binary to letter
def convert_letter(testtree: BinaryTree, letter: str) -> str:
    global result
    if testtree == None:
        return False
    elif testtree.root == letter:
        return True        
    else:  
        if convert_letter(testtree.left, letter) == True:
            result += "1"
            return result
        elif convert_letter(testtree.right, letter) == True:
            result += "0"
            return result
     
#Test
test = 'D' #Return '10'
convert_letter(BINARY, test)
```

And unfortunately that's where I'm hitting a brick wall. I had tried initialising an empty string within the function, but everytime it iterates over the function it overwrites the string. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: When you do `return result` you're not returning `True` or `False`. So neither of the conditions in the caller will succeed.

Comment: `BINARY = node('START',B,A)` should probably be `BINARY = node('START',A,B)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your function will sometimes return a boolean, sometimes a string, and sometimes `None`. So with this code:

```
    if convert_letter(testtree.left, letter) == True:
        result += "1"
        return result
    elif convert_letter(testtree.right, letter) == True:
        result += "0"
        return result
```

... you are not capturing all successful searches, as a successful search would return the actual string of "0" and "1" which obviously is not `True`. In that case the execution has no `else` to go to and returns `None` -- even when the letter was found in a deeper node.

Your function should not return a boolean -- that doesn't match the type hint either. It should be a string (the result). You could reserve `None` to indicate the letter was not found.

Some other problems:

- `result += "0"` will *append* the digit, but since you already made the recursive call, you need to *prepend* the digit -- as you are higher up in the tree now.
- The initialisation of your tree makes a different tree than you put in the image: `A` should be the left child, not the right child. So it should be `join('START', A, B)`

With those fixes, you'd have this code:

```
def convert_letter(testtree: BinaryTree, letter: str) -> str:
    global result
    if testtree is None:
        result = None  # Not found here 
    elif testtree.root == letter:
        result = ''  # Found! Start a path
    elif convert_letter(testtree.left, letter) is not None:
        result = "1" + result  # Prepend
    elif convert_letter(testtree.right, letter) is not None:
        result = "0" + result  # Prepend
    else:
        result = None  # Not found here
    return result
```

If you also correct to use `join('START', A, B)`, then the output will be `10`.

### Better Practice

There are some things you can do better:

- Don't use a global variable for storing the function result. As you *return* it, you can capture the `result` you get from a recursive call as a local variable, prepend to it, and return it again.
- The definition of `EMPTY` makes your tree unnecessarily big. Just use `None` to denote an empty tree.
- Don't call a node's value `root`. A rooted tree has only *one* root, and it is a node, not a value of a node. So call that attribute `value` or `data`, but not `root`.
- The `join` function is nice, but why not use the constructor for that feature? The constructor can take those arguments as optional and immediately initialise the `left` and `right` attributes with those arguments.
- The code-comment above the `convert_letter` function describes the opposite from what the function does.

Taking all that into account, your code could look like this:

```
class BinaryTree:
    def __init__(self, value, left: 'BinaryTree'=None, right: 'BinaryTree'=None):
        self.value = value
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

def convert_letter(tree: BinaryTree, letter: str) -> str:
    if not tree:
        return # Not found here, return None
    if tree.value == letter:
        return ""  # Bingo: return an empty path
    # No more global. path is a local variable
    path = convert_letter(tree.left, letter)
    if path is not None:
        return "1" + path
    path = convert_letter(tree.right, letter)
    if path is not None:
        return "0" + path

# Look how nice it is to create a tree using the constructor arguments
binary = BinaryTree("Start",
    BinaryTree("A",
        BinaryTree("C"), BinaryTree("D")
    ),
    BinaryTree("B",
        BinaryTree("E"), BinaryTree("F")
    )
)

# Test
test = 'D'
print(convert_letter(binary, test))  # 10
```

Comment: Thanks, this was a great explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I took the liberty of simplfying your code a bit let me know if you have any questions about how this works.

```
class node:
    """A rooted binary tree"""
    def __init__(self, value = None, left = None, right = None):
        self.value = value
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

C = node('C')
D = node('D')
E = node('E')
F = node('F')
A = node('A',C,D)
B = node('B',E,F)
BINARY = node('START',B,A)

def convert_letter(n,letter):
    if n.value == letter:
        return "1"+(convert_letter(n.left,letter) if not n.left is None else "")+(convert_letter(n.right,letter)if not n.right is None else "")
    else:
        return "0"+(convert_letter(n.left,letter) if not n.left is None else "")+(convert_letter(n.right,letter)if not n.right is None else "")

def walk(n):
    return n.value+(walk(n.left) if not n.left is None else "")+(walk(n.right) if not n.right is None else "")

test = 'D'
print(convert_letter(BINARY, test))
print(walk(BINARY))
```

Comment: The OP is looking for the result `"10"`

Answer (score 0):

This is not how I would personally structure an answer, but I think it most closely follows what you are attempting. The shortcoming of your answer only being that you are only returning one value, but kind of tracking two values. Note, I have taken the liberty of correcting:

```py
BINARY = join('START',A,B)
```

Let's modify your method to return both a Boolean indicating if the letter was found as well as the indicator of the path.

```py
def convert_letter2(testtree: BinaryTree, letter: str):
    if not testtree:
        return (False, "")

    if testtree.root == letter:
        return (True, "")

    test, val = convert_letter2(testtree.left, letter)
    if test:
        return (True, "1" + val)

    test, val = convert_letter2(testtree.right, letter)
    if test:
        return (True, "0" + val)

    return (False, "")
```

Then if we:

```py
print(convert_letter2(BINARY, "D")[1])
```

We should get back `"10"`

Comment: Thanks for helping with this, really helped.